# Python: Editing list while iterating over it

Tags: python, iterator

There are some related questions on Stack but I wanted to be as clear as possible. I am using Python 3

If I have a list, `N`, and I use the following code:

```
N = [1,2,3,4,6,7,8]
for x in N:
    N[x] = N[x] * -1
return N
```

I am getting a `Index out of range error`. I understand you shouldn't be adding and deleting elements while iterating over a list, but I wanted a clear definition of why the above example won't work.To me, it seems like there shouldn't be a problem. In the first iteration, `x` should evaluate to `1`. So if I want to edit `N[1]`, I don't see why I wouldn't be able to.

As a side note, I know `enumerate()` is the proper way to do it.

Comment: You need `enumerate`  `for x, value in enumerate(N):`

Comment: You need to correct the indentation in you code.

Comment: You mix `for <elem> in <collection>` syntax with `for i in range(len(<coll>)): <coll>[i]` indexing, chose only one ;>

Comment: Think if you really want `x` to have values of list items in `for` loop? Or you want `x` to have serial index values.

Answer (score 2):

Use `enumerate`

**Ex:**

```
N = [1,2,3,4,6,7,8]
for x, value in enumerate(N):
    N[x] = value * -1
print(N)
```

or a list comprehension.

**Ex:**

```
N = [x * -1 for x in N]
```

Comment: How about `N[x] = value * -1`? Also, it's confusing how `x` is the index in the first, but the value in the second snippet.

Comment: @tobias_k. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In `for x in N:`, `x` takes on each *value* in `N`, then you use it like an index. Lists in Python are 0-indexed, so you get an Index out of range error when you reach the end of the list and try to access `N[8]`, which doesn't exist. You can use `for x in range(len(N)):` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is actually a little different: you're treating *members* of the list as if they were *indices* of the list. Since `N[8]` doesn't exist, that's where your error is coming from. I think what you meant to do was:

```
N = [1,2,3,4,6,7,8]
for x in range(len(N)):
    N[x] = N[x] * -1
return N
```

Answer (score 0):

You are enumerating in a wrong way

```
N = [1,2,3,4,6,7,8]
for i, x in enumerate(N):
    N[i] = N[i] * -1
return N
```

Comment: The second example doesn't change the list. It only assigns to the variable `x`

Answer (score 0):

In the first iteration, `x=1` which means `N[1]` equals `2` and so your new `N[1]` becomes `2 * -1` = `-2`. Now when `x` is `8` since you are using `for x in N`, your code tries to access `N[8]` but since the length of `N` is `8`, the indexing starts from `0` and goes up to `7`. Hence there is no index `8` and hence you get an error `Index out of range error`

Answer (score 0):

Use **good ol' lambda's** or a specific callable in list comprehension:

lambda:

```
N = [1,2,3,4,6,7,8]
M = [(lambda x:-x)(element) for element in N]
print(M)
```

callable/function:

```
def negate(x):
    return -x

N = [1,2,3,4,6,7,8]
M = [negate(element) for element in N]
print(M)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code here -

```
N = [1,2,3,4,6,7,8]
for x in N: 
# x will be 1, 2, 3, 4
```

And the way you are accessing is -

```
N[x]
```

But indices run from 0 to n-1, where n-1 is the last element. Also, in your list, you are missing a `5` so indices will change badly. If you had

```
N = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

your code would have worked fine. But since that's not the case, you'd have to use `range` like -

```
for i in range(len(N)):
    N[i] = N[i] * -1
```